# Increase value of an object in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to send request to a mongodb database. For example I have this object:

```
{
  id: "1",
  requestType: {
    "api1": {
      count: 12,
      firstTime: 12
    },
    "api2": {
      count: 6,
      firstTime: 18
    }
  }
}
```

after getting data by "id" I want to append another row to "requestType" if it doesn't exist. for example "api3":{count:56,firstTime:11}.
after that I want to increase count property of each requestType object if it exists. for example if my api name is "api3" change count to 57.

currently I'm using this query by mongoose:

```
apiAttemptsModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, {
  $set: {
    requestType.api3: {
      count: 56,
      firstTime: 11
    }
  }
}, {
  upsert: true,
  new: true
}, function(err, row) {
  if (err) {
    callback('err is ' + err)
  } else {
    callback(row);
  }
});
```

But this code only will add another row in object.

Comment: according to me you need to change data type of requestType from Object {} to Array [] then you can push the new element in this array

Comment: @ManjeetThakur I edited the post, pushing the data is not my issue. I want to increase count value if the apiName exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $inc operator.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/